# PySpark: PartitionBy leaves the same value in column by which partitioned multiple times

Tags: pyspark, partition-by

I need to partitionBy in order to get distinct values in the `time` and `match_instatid` column, but it only produces distinct values about half the time

```
window_match_time_priority = Window.partitionBy(col("match_instatid"),col("time")).orderBy(col("match_instatid"),col("time"), priority_udf(col("type")).desc())
```

```
with_owner = match.select('match_instatid', "time", "type",
                F.last(col("team_instatid")).over(window_match_time_priority).alias('last_team'),                                                                   
                   F.last(col("type")).over(window_match_time_priority).alias('last_action')) \
                   .withColumn("owner", owner_assignment_udf(col("last_team"), col("last_action")))
```

You can see that the last_action column is duplicated for only some of the rows with same time, but should be for all. 
There should be only one value for owner and last_action per unique time value

[image: Picture of partitionedBy dataframe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as the window. For F.last to work the window must be unbounded. F.first works without it being unbounded.

```
window_match_time_priority = Window.partitionBy(col("match_instatid"),col("time")).orderBy(col("match_instatid"),col("time"), priority_udf(col("type")).desc())\
.rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
```